# Check if 1 out of 2 elements isDisplayed in Protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

In my test in Protractor I am expecting to see ***element1*** Or ***element2*** at the end, I found a "solution" which works only if ***element1*** is displayed and ***element2*** is not on the page

```
expect(element1.isDisplayed() || element2.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

In case if ***element1*** is not on the page but ***element2***  is there - i am getting an error:

```
 Failed: No element found using locator: ...(element1 locator)
```

I cannot write test where only one expectation is possible, this is test with Data and in my case 2 results are possible.
How can i validate if one of two elements isDisplayed on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `Jasmine` understand the expression `element1.isDisplayed() || element2.isDisplayed()` ,  so ever the two elements are not display, the assertion still pass.

The [ExpectedConditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) API supply `and/or` operation.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var condition = EC.or(EC.visibilityOf(element1), EC.visibilityOf(element2));

expect(condition()).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that isDisplayed() is the correct function you want to use.

Is your element actually rendered but just set to be hidden, or is it not even in the page? If it is just hidden, then it's OK to use isDisplayed(). If it is not in the page, then you need to find a better way to wrap the check for your elements .isDisplayed() or find a more appropriate function even.

What happens there is that your test tries to determine if element1.isDisplayed() is true or false and instead it gets a **'No element found using locator: element1'**. Let's say, if your locator is id='my-element-1' it simply means that webdriver tried to locate in your rendered page an element with id 'my-element-1' and found nothing, whereas by using element1.isDisplayed() you are asking webdriver to tell you whether element1 visibility is hidden or not.

Bottomline, [isDisplayed returns a promise](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed) and you gotta handle it appropriately or else you're going to be in trouble whenever it returns something other than your expectation.